# How do I change file name from Hex into Char?

Tags: python

I want to change mp3 file name in a directory from Hex into normal char.
The problem is I am not sure how to handle '  ' when converting hex into char as a new filename. 
How can I do this?

The file name is for example like this.

```
6a6f6e676572656e.mp3
```

And, file name cannot contain '' so that I cannot make it like this...

```
'6a6f6e676572656e'.mp3
```

I tried as following but it did not work..

```py
bytes.fromhex("'" + filename[:-4] + "'").decode('utf-8')
```

This is the whole code.

```py
import os
for filename in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\..."):
    os.rename(filename, bytes.fromhex('filename[:-4]').decode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Can you post the original filename?

Comment: What kind of `''` quotes are you talking about? Are they present in the file name?

Comment: What is a "hex" filename or a "normal char" filename? In Python, a filename is a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not make string your variable: using 'filename[:-4]':

```
import os
for filename in os.listdir(r"C:\Users\..."):
    os.rename(filename, bytes.fromhex(filename).decode('utf-8'))
```

should work if your filenames are hex; if you have some strange characters just use .replace to remove them